# Pull data from Google Sheet based on Date

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vlookup

Trying to pull date from a sheet based on Date. So I have a sheet, named January and a sheet named Test. I want to pull all the data from the January sheet that is dated 1/1/2016. I have tried a few VLookups but have had no success.

As seen in the image below, when I select the date in the box, Id like all the data from the 2nd image dated 1/1/2016 to show in the cells shown?

![January]https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGSnY.jpg
![Test]https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZmQb.jpg

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance from a newbie

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one more sheet temporarily to pull the data based on date entered. And then use `SORT()` function in **Test** sheet to get report.

Refer google spreadsheet, I created [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qJVtkMI_QwxLkNNXsfnb4-j_fch_11QE9dHvYCVYDT0). In this sheet, you have permission to enter date in **Test** sheet **B1** column. You then get output based on date entered from sheet **January** and **Temp**. I followed below steps.

1. **Temp** sheet has formula for all cells (same position as **January** sheet), it will only display records if date matches Test!B2. That is, 
   `Temp!A2 = IF(Test!$B$1=January!$A2,January!A2,"")`
   `Temp!B2 = IF(Test!$B$1=January!$A2,January!B2,"")`
   `Temp!C2 = =IF(Test!$B$1=January!$A2,January!C2,"")`
   Repeat in **Temp** cells for all positions in **January** cells.
2. **Test** sheet cell A4 is set with `=SORT(Temp!A2:C22,1,TRUE)` so that it will display records sorted based on Date column in **Temp** sheet. This will you get only records of whatever date entered in **Test!B1**.